# selenium - webcrawler- find_elements_by_css_selector(webelement).text does not work but need an iterator. why?

Tags: python, selenium, iterator, web-crawler

as the question suggests why is the below wrong code would not work but the correct code would?

arent they eseentially the same thing? i looked around and saw the post that explained that the python native list works but the selenium created object list in this case will not work

But i did not really understand it in its essence, could anyone please elaborate alittle further in plain english for a novice programmer please

Wrong Code:

```
mainText = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
    'div.post_content.clearfix > p').text
    print(mainContentDetail)
```

List has no attribute text

Correct code:

```
mainText = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
    'div.post_content.clearfix > p')
for mainContentDetail in mainText:
    print(mainContentDetail.text)
```

Comment: find_elements_... (with an s) returns a list. you can use the one without an "s" if you know it is a unique element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use below, you rae trying to list of elements with css selector matching with div.post_content.clearfix > p.

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
    'div.post_content.clearfix > p')
```

And when you write below, you are trying to get the text from multiple elements. But text method works to get the text associated with a single element. As you are trying to get the Text from multiple elements using text method it throws error.

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
    'div.post_content.clearfix > p').text
```

Where as in below code you have list element to a list called mainText and you are iterating through each element in mainText list and and then getting the text from each element using text method. hence it works.

```
mainText = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
    'div.post_content.clearfix > p')
for mainContentDetail in mainText:
    print(mainContentDetail.text)
```